# Recording of personal data while the Apple Watch is locked?

Tags: apple-watch, geolocation, health.app, health-kit

Does Apple Watch (or, more specifically, Apple Watch Ultra, in case of different behavior) record personal information while the device is locked, and then associate it with the active account, when unlocked?

For example, it's known that when the device is unlocked and strapped to your arm, it collects various kinds of **health (and fitness) data**. It is also known that a variety of built-in applications as well as various features of the device make use of (probably live-) **location data** (well, I'm not sure if things like "Significant Locations" takes the location from Watch or from iPhone - but I believe the point is clear).

My question is actually two related following phases and questions -

1. *WHEN LOCKED* - **While the device is locked** (for example, I strapped it to my hand, but I didn't type a password) **is data being collected?** Is it including person-specific data (such as health information, Pulse, and maybe even Steps Count) or only device-specific data (such as geo-location, sounds)?
2. *WHEN UNLOCKED* - As soon **as Unlocking is performed - is the collected data automatically associated** with the iCloud account active on the device? And/or to the local storage on the device? And synced with the iPhone that is linked to the Watch?

Important to Note, the specific distinct referencing to Health and Location, separately, is important - since those are two different kinds of collected data (the 1st is device-specific as mentioned, and the 2nd is person-specific)